# Incremental data stored procedure load from Azure Blob to Snowflake

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-blob-storage

I have a JSON file in Azure Blob storage and need to fetch the data incrementally Azure Blob to SNOWFLAKE. Currently, I am copying data using COPY INTO command manually everyday.

Need Stored procedure to fetch the incremental data from Azure Blob to Snowflake. The stored procedure will be scheduled through Azure data factory. Can someone help me with stored procedure?

```
Copy Logic:
==============
copy into "EMP_DB"."EMPLOYEE_HOURS_JSON"
from stg.temp_Emp/
file_format = (type = json)
pattern='.*json';
    
Copying data from JSON table to Actual Table:
=============================================
INSERT INTO EMP_DB.EMP_DAILY_HRS
select 
p.value:emp_name::STRING as EMP_NAME,
p.value:emp_id::STRING as EMP_ID,
p.value:emp_daily_hrs::STRING as EMP_DAILY_HRS,
p.value:date::DATE as date
FROM EMP_DB.EMPLOYEE_HOURS_JSON p where date = CURRENT_DATE();
```

Comment: Have you considered using Snowpipe instead?

Comment: @MikeWalton Does Snowpipe can do scheduled incremental loads? If it can do, Can you please provide me an example to approach Snowpipe?

Comment: Snowpipe ingests data into Snowflake as soon as it lands on Azure Blob.  If you want to schedule the downstream updates of that data, you can ingest from Azure Blob using Snowpipe into a staging table, put a STREAM on top of that and then schedule a task to execute to pull the data from that STREAM into the downstream target table.